# Insert data in json file

Tags: python, json, file

The code inserts wrong structure json into file

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

urls = {}
urls['Av'] = {'Áa', 'Bb'}

data = {}
for key, value in urls.items(): 
    for x in value: 

        url = 'https://www.google.pt/search?q=' + key + '%20' + x
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        html = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        a = soup.find("body")

        for child in a.find_all("div", {'class': 'g'}):
            h2 = child.find("span", {'class': 'Q8LRLc'})
            div = child.find("a", {'class': 'Fx4vi'})

        data[key] = []
        data[key].append({'h2': h2, 'div': div})
        print(data)

        with open("data_file.json", "a") as write_file: 
            json.dump(data, write_file, indent=4)

        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Define "wrong structure", then proceed to define "good structure". Then give us example data that you would like to store and what it currently stores. If you have any errors, please post the full stack trace in a code block.

Comment: It output this: {
    "Av": [
        {
            "h2": null,
            "div": null
        }
    ]
}{
    "Av": [
        {
            "h2": null,
            "div": null
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Please include this as an edit in the post in a code block, not as a comment

Comment: btw, be very careful with `with open("data_file.json", "a")`. This means that you are appending to the file, each time writing a new version of `data`. This will result in a technically invalid `.json` file. Did you mean to have this after the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: I try that but it don´t save the first result, only the last one

Comment: Ok, I see. That's because every time round the `for x in value:` loop you are overwriting `data[key] = []`. So please update your question with an expected contents of `data_file.json`.

Comment: @Alvaro You still haven't updated your **question** instead of the comment section. Voting to close this question until more details have been added.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to have `data[key] = []` just before `for x in value:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a bunch of issues, most are things either being inside a loop when they should be outside, or outside when they should be in.

- You set your variables `h2` and `div` inside the loop `for child in a.find_all("div", {'class': 'g'}):`, but you add them to `data` outside the loop, so only the last values will be added.
- Additionally, you initialize the data for each key inside the loop, and it should be done outside, or it will be re-initialized each time.
- You also open the file to append to it each time, I'd just do it once.
- And, you initialize your driver in every loop.
- `requests` and `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options` are both unused imports

So, I'd change it like this:

```
urls = {}
urls['Av'] = {'Áa', 'Bb'}

data = {}
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open("data_file.json", "a") as write_file: 
    for key, value in urls.items():
        data[key] = []. # initialize only once per key

        for x in value: 
            url = 'https://www.google.pt/search?q=' + key + '%20' + x
            driver.get(url)
            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            a = soup.find("body")

            for child in a.find_all("div", {'class': 'g'}):
                h2 = child.find("span", {'class': 'Q8LRLc'})
                div = child.find("a", {'class': 'Fx4vi'})
                data[key].append({'h2': h2, 'div': div})  # update data for every h2/div found

    json.dump(data, write_file, indent=4) # This write can be done once, outside all loops!

driver.quit()
```

A little hard for me to test, but hope that helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: I think first you should `load` the JSON file and then `update` with fetched data and then write it to file with `dump` in the end.