# Just asking If this is possible to do this (Raspberry pi running Docker)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, raspberry-pi

So I've been running this program Everyday for a few weeks and it been doing me well. Its to Auto Search on Bing to get Microsoft rewards points to get free stuff (Because I'm board)And I was just wondering If I would be able to run this script on a few docker containers on a raspberry pi. For you to receive the points you also need to be signed in on a Microsoft account in a browser. Now I'm have pretty much no experience with docker and I'm not sure if it is a able to open a window with a browser. Also I would need to  sign into a account at the start on that container. BTW the reason for all of this is cause they put a cap on the number of searches you can do per day per account. Yes I know this is against Bing's ToS and I have excepted the risk.

Here is the code (you can copy it if you want)

````
import time
import webbrowser
import requests
import random

def Diff(li1, li2):
    return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))

url = 'https://www.bing.com/'

word_site = "https://www.myhelpfulguides.com/keywords.txt"

response = requests.get(word_site)
words = response.text.splitlines()

for i in range(60):
  f = open('D:/Bing Auto Searcher/usedKeywords.txt', 'r')
  used = f.read().splitlines()

  new = Diff(words, used)

  search = random.choice(new)
  f = open('D:/Bing Auto Searcher/usedKeywords.txt', 'a')
  f.write(search + "\n")
  f.close()

  webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
  sleep = random.randint(3,5)
  time.sleep(sleep)
  pyautogui.typewrite(search, interval=0.01)
  pyautogui.typewrite('\n', interval=0.1)
  pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')

  print(f"The count is {i} with a pause of {sleep} seconds between searches. We searched for {search}")  ```
````

Comment: A container is just a operating system installed in a virtual bubble of sorts. So the answer is yes, but it's a bit to complicated for a SO post. Keywords to search for: "web browser headless" and "selenium".

Comment: ok thanks, Will look into it. Before I thought a Container was just a place to run isolated code. So its closer to a VM then I thought. ok well thanks :)

Comment: Here's a post that's solving sort of what you're doing, sorta (ignore that the post itself is a bit "meh"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108358/insert-data-in-json-file